# Search multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, search

I had four different tables say table1, table2, table3, and table4 and this tables contain different data; now I want to do a search on this 4 table that will come up with one result.

```
table1-fields: 
id, product_name, price, product_category; 
table2-fields: 
id,company_name, company_description, location; 
table3-fields:
id, business_name, location, business_category;
table4-fields:
id, building_type, location, name
```

I had this form:

```
<form name="me" action="search.php"> 
<input type="text" name="search" style="width:inherit;" size="25"  
value="type your search here" 
onclick="me.search.value='';" style="font-size:small" height="20"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit2" class="button" value="SEARCH"  />
</form>
```

In search.php I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3, table4 
WHERE table1.product_name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' 
OR table2.company_name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' 
OR table3.business_name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' 
OR table4.name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'`;
```

a sql statement that will search these 4 tables at the same time.

How could I do this? Please help.

Comment: is there relationship exists among these tables?

Comment: a little more detail is required, what are you searching for, (as harigm asked: is there a relationship), do you want to search all 4  tables at once? Please be a little more specific with your question.

Comment: the tables are not actually related, these tables contains user posts: table1-products, table2-companies, table3-business, table4-buildings. I want to search this tables at the same time that will come up with one result. What could be the way to do this? -shire

Answer (score 2):

If there is a common element, like there's an ID or other identifier which is shared between each table, you can use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). This'll allow you to select rows based on data contained in each table.

You'd need to provide more information about your tables and what you're searching for for me to be able to provide a full example.

Comment: there's an id for each tables but they are not related so they don't have common element

Comment: there's an id for each tables but they are not related so they don't have common element. Table1- has fields id, product_name, price, product_category; Table2 has fields id,company_name, company_description, location; Table3 has fields id, business_name, location, business_category; Table4 has fields id, building_type, location, name.

Answer (score 0):

Write a query for each table that returns the result in the same columns in each query; use UNION to joint them into 1 result set:

```
(SELECT id, name from table1 where name='bob')
UNION
(SELECT moar_id as id, nickname as name from table2 WHERE nickname='bob')
UNION
(SELECT account_id as id, fullname as name from table2 WHERE fullname='bob')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: could I declare something like this? $sql = "(SELECT  * FROM post_bus WHERE bus_name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR location LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR bus_category LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR bus_description LIKE '%" . $name ."%') UNION (SELECT  * FROM post_jobs WHERE job_category LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR company_name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR location LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR job_responsibilities LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR company_description LIKE '%" . $name ."%')"

Comment: unfortunately i got this error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in... what could be wrong?

Comment: that means something in your php code that tries to connect to the database is wrong; not with the query.

Comment: the code that tries to connect to the database? could that be the problem? but it works for other queries.. thanks for answering, i'll try checking it